# Parse some string date to another format

Tags: java, android, date, simpledateformat, android-date

I have problem **formating date.**

**From** : EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z (example : Mon, 05 Jan 2014 15:10:00 +0200)

**To** : dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm (example : 05/01/2014 15:10)

Here is what i tried :

```
private String formatDate(String date) {
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm");
    Date dateResult = null;
    try {
        dateResult = format.parse(date);
    }
    catch (java.text.ParseException e) {
        Log.e(TAG, "", e);
    }
    return dateResult.toString();
}
```

I get exception : **unparseable date at offset 0**

some help would be nice here thanks ;)

Comment: See [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) you can get some idea about all date formats.

Comment: I already got to see this, official doc is important so.. but it does not helps. My issue is not doc related but more about logic. But thanks

Comment: @Yume117 You are parsing your *input* using the format you said you want for your *output*. Did you make a mistake in providing your sample code here, or is that cause of your problem?

Comment: Yes i've understood that far, i'm trying the posts below without good result for now

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need two times converting. For example:

```
private String formatDate(String date) {
    SimpleDateFormat formatFrom = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, dd MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z ");

    java.util.Date tmpDate = formatFrom.parse(date);
    SimpleDateFormat formatTo = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm");
    return formatTo.format(tmpDate);
}
```

For my own RSS parser I use the following code to parse different date formats:

```
    if (value.contains("+")) {
        value = value.substring(0, value.lastIndexOf("+") - 1);
    }

    String[] patterns = {//"EEE, dd MMM yyyy hh:mm:ss UTC",
            "yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' HH:mm:ss z",
            "EEE, MMM d, ''yy",
            "yyyyy.MMMMM.dd GGG hh:mm aaa",
            "EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z",
            "yyMMddHHmmssZ",
            "d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z",
            "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss",
            "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss'Z'",
            "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'",
            "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ",
            "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ",
            "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssz",
            "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSz",
            "EEE, d MMM yy HH:mm:ssz",
            "EEE, d MMM yy HH:mm:ss",
            "EEE, d MMM yy HH:mm z",
            "EEE, d MMM yy HH:mm Z",
            "EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z",
            "EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z",
            "EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss ZZZZ",
            "EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm z",
            "EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm Z",
            "d MMM yy HH:mm z",
            "d MMM yy HH:mm:ss z",
            "d MMM yyyy HH:mm z",
            "d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss z"};

    for (int i = 0; i < patterns.length; i++) {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat(patterns[i], Locale.ENGLISH);
        try {
            pubdate = sdf.parse(value);

            break;
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }
```

Comment: Try to switch "d" to "dd"

Comment: Just tried it's the same. Seriously dates are a pain to deal with :(

Comment: Just tried it's the same. Maybe the dateformat is wrong but i can't figure it out

Comment: Where you get your date? You know what date in what format you are recieving? I Will update my post, maybe it will help you.

Comment: i get it from xml stream. Yes i the format is always the same i logged it. For example : "Fri, 12 Oct 2012 06:57:39 +0200"

Comment: Is it important to save time zone?

Comment: @RomanBlack Unable to parse `Sunday, 18th February` with `EEEE, dd'th' MMMM` not working what may be the issue?

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SimpleDateFormat form = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
SimpleDateFormat postFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm");

String inputdate = "Mon, 05 Jan 2014 15:10:00 +0200";

Date date = null;

    try {
        date = form.parse(inputdate);

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    }

String resultdate = postFormater.format(date);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try code below:

```
String parseStringDate(String sqlDate) {
    String strDate = "";
    java.util.Date utilDate;

    SimpleDateFormat sqlDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("EEE, d MMM yyyy HH:mm:ss Z");
    try {
        Calendar calTempDate = Calendar.getInstance();
        utilDate = sqlDateFormat.parse(sqlDate);

        calTempDate.setTime(utilDate);
        strDate = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MMM/yyyy HH:mm").format(calTempDate.getTime());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return strDate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

## Incorrect sample data

Your example data of `Mon, 05 Jan 2014 15:10:00 +0200` is incorrect. That date was a Sunday, not a Monday.

## java.time

The modern way is with the java.time classes.

Your input has a format that conforms with [RFC 1123](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1123). The java.time classes include a [formatter for that specific format](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#RFC_1123_DATE_TIME).

```
String input = "Sun, 05 Jan 2014 15:10:00 +0200";
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.RFC_1123_DATE_TIME ;
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse( input , f );
```

> odt.toString(): 2014-01-05T15:10+02:00

See [live code in IdeOne.com](http://ideone.com/dLbBTx).

As for generating a string in other formats, that is already covered many times in Stack Overflow. Search for `DateTimeFormatter` class.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

With a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) complying with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later, you may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. No need for strings or java.sql.* classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later
- Built-in.
- Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
- Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)
- Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))
- Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
- For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

Comment: Unable to parse Sunday, 18th February with EEEE, dd'th' MMMM not working ?

Comment: @SagarHudge Post your own Question with specifics and with a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @SagarHudge (a) Specify a `Locale`. (b) You **need a year** with that input. You cannot determine a day-of-week without a year. Otherwise, for a month and day without any year and without any time-of-day or time zone, use `YearMonth` class.  `LocalDate.parse( "Sunday, 18th February 2018" , DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "EEEE, dd'th' MMMM uuuu" , Locale.US )  )`