# Date not coming in desired format

Tags: android, date, calendar, calendarview

In my App, I am using Calendar View. So , I have drawn a custom Calendar View using this [tutorial](http://droidwalk.blogspot.in/2012/11/android-calendar-sample.html). As I want the selected date format in `dd-MM-yyyy` so for this I have changed this line

```
df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
```

into this,

```
df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.US);
```

And after changing that line when I run my App I got this output,

[image]

but when I select any cell its gives correct format of date,

[image]

Where am I wrong ?

The whole code is same as [tutorial](http://droidwalk.blogspot.in/2012/11/android-calendar-sample.html). I've just changed one line.

Please help.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In `CalendarAdapter` class no need to change date format.

Use this inside `CalendarAdapter`.

```
df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.US);
```

When display time in `CalendarView.java` you can use this

```
df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.US);
```

Comment: I have already changed line like this `df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.US);` in `CalendarView.java` but nothing happening..

Comment: As you told i haven't changed line in `CalendarAdapter` but in `CalendarView` when I changed the line the app got crashed!

Comment: I changed like this,
`DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.US);
 String str=df.format(selectedGridDate);
 showToast(str);`

Is this correct way ?

Comment: Where I am displaying Toast..
I changed like this, 
DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy", Locale.US); 
String str=df.format(selectedGridDate); showToast(str); 
Is this correct way ?

Comment: i think something wrong there..Now try new thing that don't change date format directly. but get in `"yyyy-MM-dd"` format in whole app then convert string date to another date. Please Refer this [parse-some-string-date-to-another-format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21624110/parse-some-string-date-to-another-format/21624214#21624214)

Answer (score 0):

change this

```
String gridvalueString = separatedTime[2].replaceFirst("^0*","");// taking last part of date. ie; 2 from 2012-12-02.
int gridvalue = Integer.parseInt(gridvalueString);
```

to

```
String gridvalueString = separatedTime[0].replaceFirst("^0*","");// taking last part of date. ie; 2 from 2012-12-02.
int gridvalue = Integer.parseInt(gridvalueString);
```

because i think your date format is like "dd-MM-yyyy" instead of "yyyy-MM-dd"

Comment: Tried this. But same result in `yyyy-MM-dd`